# passing column name as variable in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

Variants of this question have been asked a lot, I also read about NSE.
Still I cannot figure this out.

This is easy:

```
library(dplyr)
data(cars)

cars %>%
  group_by(speed) %>%
  summarise(d = mean(dist))
```

Now I want to use variable x to pass the dist column to mean

`x <- "dist"`

Of course this does not work:

```
cars %>%
  group_by(speed) %>%
  summarise(d = mean(x))
```

So I use SE version of summarise:

```
cars %>%
  group_by(speed) %>%
  summarise_(d = mean(x))
```

Ok, does not work, so I have to add `~` as well:

```
cars %>%
  group_by(speed) %>%
  summarise_(d = ~mean(x))
```

Still does not work, but if use `dist` instead of `x`:

```
cars %>%
  group_by(speed) %>%
  summarise_(d = ~mean(dist))
```

This works, but doesn't use x.

```
cars %>%
  group_by(speed) %>%
  summarise_(d = ~mean(~x))
```

This also doesn't work.

I'm basically monkeying around without any idea how to make this work, or why it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cars %>%
    group_by(speed) %>%
    summarise_each_(funs(mean), vars(matches(x)))
```

Comment: Thank you! My problem is, was doing something more like this `cars %>%
  group_by(speed) %>%
  summarise_(d = ~quantile(dist, c(0.95), na.rm =T)[1])` Do you also have a solution for that?

Comment: I tend to define a function with the argument first, e.g. `quantiles <- function(x) quantile(x, .95, na.rm=T)`. This way, the `summarise_each` can still run accordingly: `cars %>% group_by(speed) %>%  summarise_each_(funs(quantiles), vars(matches("dist")))`